# Why getting ffmpeg error/warning : Past duration 0.933205 too large ? Getting a lot of it when recording the desktop as video file

Tags: ffmpeg

This is the command :

ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p player.mp4

Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-vsync 0` when recording a live capture.

Also, your ffmpeg is 4.0 or earlier. The message won't appear with your original command in 4.1 or later.